# How to define template outside component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to build a table component (with standard features) where rows should be defined as a template.

At the moment I've tried this way (code simplified):

1) parent component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'simple-grid',
    template: `<table><tbody>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
          <template
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
              [ngOutletContext]="{'item': item, 'i': i}">
          </template>
   </ng-container>
       </tbody></table>
    `
})
export class SimpleGridComponent {
    @Input()
    items: any[] = [];
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    template: any;
}
```

2) usage:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'simple-grid',
    template: `
       <simple-grid [items]="users" >
          <template>
            <tr [class.even]="i%2==0" [class.odd]="i%2!=0">
              item: {{item?.id}} {{ someProperty }} {{id}}
            </tr>
          </template>
       </simple-grid>`
})
MyPage{
   public users: Users = [{id: 1, name='one'}, {id: 2, name='two' }];
   public someProperty: string = 'dummy';
}
```

Result:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        item: dummy
     </tr>
     <tr>
        item: dummy
     </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

so:

- Template is used
- Rows are correctly repeated
- but I'm not able to show **item** properties; rows are not bound to the "item" in the *ngFor, but the MyPage itself.
  ps: if I select a row with Augury, in console $a.context contains correctly the 
  item and the index.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that template syntax needs "let-" attribute to use items available in the context of the template.

So, I've fixed the code in this way:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'simple-grid',
   template: `
   <simple-grid [items]="users" >
      <template let-item="item" let-index="i">
        <tr [class.even]="index%2==0" [class.odd]="index%2!=0">
          item: {{item?.id}} {{ someProperty }} {{id}}
        </tr>
      </template>
   </simple-grid>`
})
MyPage{
   public users: Users = [{id: 1, name='one'}, {id: 2, name='two' }];
}
```

example in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PwSpjy4KTYjstGWTWP24?p=preview